# kafkaMessageListenerContainer.start() is throwing NoSuchMethod Error in runtime

Tags: spring, spring-kafka

I am trying to create a kafka Listener in Spring without using annotation, the compilation is successful, but during app start up , I am getting below error:

```
 [ERR] Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer]: Factory method 'messageListenerContainer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(ZLjava/util/function/Supplier;)V
2022-12-20T22:23:41.308+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
2022-12-20T22:23:41.308+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
2022-12-20T22:23:41.308+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] ... 26 more
```

Comment: You must provide an example of the code, stack trace in order to check the error

Comment: `NoSuchMethodError` almost always indicates a dependency version issue. Please share your pom/gradle file

Comment: My application is a multi-module project where I have multiple poms. But the dependency I am using is org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:2.2.7.RELEASE and Spring boot 1.5.19.RELEASE with Spring 4.3.22.RELEASE version. And the error I am getting whenever I am trying to call the start method on org.springframework.kafka.listener.MessageListenerContainer

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved by downgrading spring-kafka version from 2.1.0.RELEASE to 1.3.0.RELEASE.